# DrawerLayout unresolved in ActionBarDrawerToggle

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation-drawer, actionbardrawertoggle

i am trying to build a navigation drawer and i am using a actionbardrawertoggle for this. I set the parameters and there is no errors associated with them. The only thing is that my id of my drawerlayout in activity_main.xml isn't "recognized" as a parameter. I checked the ids and they are all well. I tried to change the id to see a difference in the error but there is none. As you will see the ids are identical. I also tried to change the actionbardrawertoggle to one with toolbar because i thought maybe there was a problem with the order of parameters but nothing changed. The id's name is drawer. Do you know what i am missing?
Thanks for your help

Here is my code:

````
//Here is MainActivity:

package zeinfederico.example.tasklead_newversion

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.system.Os.close
import android.system.Os.open
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.toolbar))

        val drawerToggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer , R.string.open, R.string.close)
        drawer.addDrawerListener(drawerToggle)
        drawerToggle.syncState()

        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
    }
} 

//Here is activity_main.xml

 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">
        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:menu="@menu/main_menu"
        />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>```
````

Answer (score 0):

what is `drawer`? you haven't initialized such value on Java/Kotlin side, so it is unresolved...

put this just after `setContentView` and `setSupportActionBar`

```
val drawer = findViewById<DrawerLayout>(R.id.drawer)
```